# Is a topological vector space path-connected?

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, examples-counterexamples, topological-vector-spaces, path-connected

So in the text *Functional Analysis* Walter Rudin says that

> "A topological vector space is a real or complex vector space equipped with a $T_1$-topology with respect to which the vector operations are continuous."

Now for a real t.v.s. $X$ it seem to me that the function
$$
\gamma:[0,1]\ni t\longrightarrow x_1+t\cdot(x_2-x_1)\in X
$$
for any $x_1,x_2\in X$ is continuous: indeed the vector sum $s:X\times X\longrightarrow X$ and the scalar-vector product $p:\Bbb R\times X\longrightarrow X$ are continuous and moreover even the functions
$$
\varphi:[0,1]\ni t\longrightarrow(t,x_2-x_1)\in\Bbb R\times X\quad\text{and}\quad\psi:X\ni x\longrightarrow(x_1,x)\in X\times X
$$
is continuous with respect product topology and thus observing that
$$
\gamma=s\circ\psi\circ p\circ\varphi
$$
we conclude that $\gamma$ is continuous. So if $\gamma$ is continuous then $X$ is path connected and so connected and I think that this is a really relevant result but unfortunately any author (even Rudin) does not observe this so that I thought to put a specific question where I ask clarification about. Morover I would like to know if also a complex t.v.s. is path connected. So could somoeone help me, please?

Comment: Yes, real or complex topological vector spaces (and any convex subsets of them)  are (path) connected.

Comment: @geetha290krm Okay, so is correct the proof for the real case? how prove it in the complex case?

Comment: Exactly the same proof for the complex case. Why do you think your proof breaks down?

Comment: @geetha290krm I never exactly thought that my proof was bad: what surprised me was that nobody observes this relevant result so that I thought that it was false, that's all.

Comment: Anyway I do not see immediately how adjust the proof for the complex case: could you show this, please?

Comment: proof: TVS are closed under linear combinations. therefore they're closed under convex combinations. every point on the path between 2 points is a convex combo. QED.

Comment: @geetha290krm Perhaps I understood: the same arguments woks because $\Bbb R$ is embeddable into $\Bbb C$, right?

Comment: $\Bbb R$ is not just embeddable in $\Bbb C$. We usually consider it to be an actual subset of $\Bbb C$. Thus your line segment works exactly as well in a complex vector space as it does in a real vector space, since $t$ is also a complex number.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Sorry, but I know that $\Bbb C$ is **exactly** equal to $\Bbb R^2$ equipped with usual vector sum and with the binary operation
$$x∗y≡(x_1,x_2)∗(y_1,y_2):=(x_1y_1−x_2y_2,x_1y_2+x_2y_1)$$
for any $x,y∈\Bbb R^2$. Now the topology on $\Bbb C$ is that induced by the **usual** euclidean norm (right?) so that it **seems** to me that $\Bbb R$ is embeddable into $\Bbb C$. So where is my mistake? Could you explain, please?

Comment: That is not $\Bbb C$. That is a *model* for $\Bbb C$. You need to separate the two concepts. This is easier to explain for $\Bbb R$, which we define as a topologically complete ordered field. All such fields are isomorphic to each other, and $\Bbb R$ is simply one of them. We make no assumptions about $\Bbb R$ beyond the axioms in that definition. You can show such a field exists by building a certain set and defining operations on it that meet all the axioms, but that set and its operations are a *model* for $\Bbb R$ that carries baggage we do not need. The model is not $\Bbb R$ itself.

Comment: $\Bbb C$ is simply the smallest algebraicly closed extension field of $\Bbb R$. By extension field, we mean in particular that $\Bbb R \subset \Bbb C$. Equating $\Bbb C$ with $\Bbb R^2$ is simply a way that we can build a model for $\Bbb C$, thus proving that such an extension field exists. As with $\Bbb R$, this model carries baggage we do not need or want - in particular, having $\Bbb R \not \subset \Bbb C$. So that model is not the actual definition. Instead $\Bbb C$ is not specified beyond being an extension. So $$\Bbb N \subset \Bbb Z \subset \Bbb Q \subset \Bbb R \subset \Bbb C$$

Comment: @PaulSinclair Sorry, but I do not understand what you want mean exactly: e.g. Serge Lang into the text *Undergraduate Algebra* says that "We define a complex number to be a pair of real number....Thus the set of complex numbers, denoted by $\Bbb C$, is nothing so far but $\Bbb R^2$..." moreover also my Algebra text (*Aritmetica e Algebra* by Dikran Dikranjan and Maria Silvia Lucido) define $\Bbb C$ as Lang and as many authors (e.g. see *Introducción a la teoría de conjuntos* by José M. Muñoz Q. or *Teoría de conjuntos* by Carlos Ivorra Castillo etc...).

Comment: Otherwise how build $\Bbb C$? E.g. $\Bbb R$ is built from $\Bbb Q$ using Cauchy sequence and so a particular equivalence relation which allow to define $\Bbb R$ as a quotient space. Anyway it seem to me that the topology on $\Bbb C$ is compatibile with the euclideand topology on $\Bbb R^2$ so that $\Bbb R$ is surely embeddable into $\Bbb C$ if it is embeddable into $\Bbb R^2$ which seems homeomorphic to $\Bbb C$. So where is my mistake?

Comment: Serge Lang and the others are avoiding introducing another level of abstraction to an audience who need to learn other things at the time. But you can look at it this way: You can build $\Bbb C$ any way you like. But once you are done, turn around a redefine $\Bbb R$ to be the real subfield of $\Bbb C$. Redefine $\Bbb Q$ to be the rational subfield of $\Bbb R$, redefine $\Bbb Z$ to the integer submodule of $\Bbb Q$ and $\Bbb N$ to be either the positive or non-negative integers. And forget everything about your set $\Bbb C$ that is not a consequence of its algebraic/topological axioms.

Comment: That is how mathematicians think about these fields/modules. They are an actual chain of inclusions, and the only properties they have are those arising from the axioms, not from some construction.

Comment: @PaulSinclair So, I know  that $\Bbb N$  is not contained into $\Bbb Z$ but there exists an isomorphism of $\Bbb N$ **into** $\Bbb Z$ and same for $\Bbb Z$ and $\Bbb Q$ etc... Moreover by your last comment It seem to me that you define $\Bbb C$ or $\Bbb R$ with axiom but I do not really sure about because I do not understand English very well so that I ask a confirmation about. Anyway I thought we was discussing about the embeddabbility of $\Bbb R$ into $\Bbb C$ and not about the possibility of an inclusion of $\Bbb R$ into $\Bbb  C$.

Comment: I've described this twice. If you simply deny what I am telling you because you just know that what you've read is absolute truth and what I say doesn't fit your conception, then there is no point in my saying anything more. You will either drop off the mathematics path or eventually move past this point and learn what I was trying to tell you anyway.

Comment: That sounds more surly than I intended. My point is, I was trying to bring your mathematical sophistication up a notch, but you do not seem to be ready for that step yet. If you keep up your mathematical studies, you will be ready for and make that step fairly soon. There is no point in my trying to rush you.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Sorry, I did not want offend you: I was only trying to understand how define $\Bbb C$ differently, that's all. So by your comments I infer that it **seem** is possible use an axiomatic theory but this it seems stranger because I think it is more elementary whereas it seems you are stating that is not just elementary. Anyway I am really courious about to the point that I would be really grateful if you indicate some reference where I can study a different definition of $\Bbb C$. Forgive my words if they offended you, sorry.

Comment: I'm not offended. I merely realized that you are in a place where you are not ready to comprehend what I was saying. I remember that place. I went through it too. Within another year or two, you will learn that what is important about any mathematical object are the basic properties that make it what it is, not some construction. Constructions are only useful for showing that there actually is some object with the desired properties. At that point, you will understand that those properties, the "axioms", are all that is necessary for defining it.

Comment: @PaulSinclar Okay, so if you believe that I am not yet ready for well understand what $\Bbb C$ is really then I believe you because I trust in your experience that surely is more than mine. So I hope on day I will studied enough to understand this.

Comment: It is not $\Bbb C$ itself that is the issue. It is a more general view of mathematics. There is a level of abstraction in thinking about mathematics that you have not yet reached. This is normal. You've already passed several earlier levels of abstraction in your thinking. There are more coming, and this is (probably) the next one.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Well currently I think math is an art form, so there is no privileged path to prove any result, but in principle all should be equivalent: however, surely how Dalí's Christ is really different from a Christ by Donatello equally there are many really different mathematical approaches to the same problem or argument. So I hope to improve myself in the future.